# "Bad" lower functions for a Bessel process?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t, t \ge 0)$ be a Bessel($\delta$) process, for some dimension $\delta > 2$, starting, say, from $1$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be an upper semicontinuous function; assume that $f(0)=0$. Call it a lower function for $X$ if $X \ge f$ eventually.

Here is a known integral test for lower functions:

> If $f(t) t^{-1/2}$ is decreasing to $0$ then $f$ is a lower function iff $$\intop_1^\infty t^{-\delta/2} (f(t))^{\delta - 2} dt < \infty$$

My question is: what is known without the monotonicity assumption ($f t^{-1/2} \downarrow 0$)? In particular:

1. Does the same integral test work if $f$ is only assumed to be globally Holder($1/2$)? I believe that I can prove it for $\delta = 3$ and $f$ globally Sobolev $W^{1,2}$.
2. What about general functions? Is it true that if $f$ is a lower function then there is another lower function $g \ge f$ whithin some class for which the integral test is valid?

I'm particularly interested in the case $\delta = 3$.